# Scala Parallel Print Hanging the console

Tags: scala, foreach, par

I am new to this Scala world and I am trying some exercises from a book. So, I have an example that print a vector in sequential and parallel fashion. The former works perfectly and the later hangs the console.

**Code**

```
val v = Vector.range(0, 10)
v.foreach(println)
```

**Code output**

```
0123456789
```

But if I use the same code, but instead of using foearch, use par, it freezes the console

```
val v = Vector.range(0,10)
v.par.foreach(println)
```

The book I am using says that the output should be something like:

```
5678901234
```

But it hangs and the program never finishes.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: It's not obvious, but it's due to starting threads from a static initializer. There's an SO for it, I'll try to find it. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8119 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176199/scala-parallel-collection-in-object-initializer-causes-a-program-to-hang  The ticket suggests workarounds. Easiest is to make it local, `{ x.par }`.

Comment: I tested with scala 2.12.1 - and console hanged. With scala 2.11.8 works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I was just curious about the reason. I'm not using it in a current project.

Comment: I got this to work by starting the repl with `scala -Yrepl-class-based` (per [this comment](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8119?focusedCommentId=67218&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-67218)), but everything else I tried (including wrapping various parts of the command in braces) did not work.

Comment: Further evidence: this works in the default repl: `class X { Vector.range(0,10). par.foreach(print) } ; new X`, but this doesn't `object X { Vector.range(0,10). par.foreach(print) } ; X`.

Comment: Here is another one that doesn't work: `import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool; import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport; var v = Vector.range(0,10).par; v.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(4)); v.foreach(print)`. I thought maybe creating the pool explicitly would help, but it seems to still be lazily evaluated, and I still get a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to post whole the program wich is hanged.

I've just tested it with scala 2.12.8 and jvm 1.8.0_161:

```
object MainClassss {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val v = Vector.range(0,10)
    (0 to 999999).foreach(_ => v.par.foreach(println))
  }
}
```

the program has executed well with output and hasn't hanged.

If your program reproduced the aforementioned issue you need to take a thread dump by:

```
$ jstack <PID>
```

where PID is the process id.

Or you can take by `jvisualvm` jvm tool.

You can analyze why your program is hanged owing to caught thread dump if the program has some code blocking it from execution.