# Parallel operation hangs in scala

Tags: macos, scala

Scala noob here:
`val pv = (1 to 100).toArray.par`

Now I want to apply a map function to this parallel collection `pv`

`pv.map(_ * 2)`

However the above operation hangs. Any reason why?

Using Scala version `2.12.4` on a Mac OS X (High Sierra)

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I have the same config (Scala .2.12.4, Mac OS X (High Sierra), and the problem is not reproducable. Maybe it hangs in another part? Could you post a reproducable example (full function etc.)?

Comment: I am using the scala interpreter and I only have the above two lines.

Answer (score 5):

Seems this is caused by static initializer deadlock, see:

https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/34

This issue point out in the **repl**, when create a **parallel collection**, repl will generate a **wraper** for it, when init, it will cause **dead lock**.

and it also can be reproduce in program from the:

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8119

```
object Foreacher {
  val n = 0
  val m = List(1).par.foreach(_ => n)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("Hello, all")
}
```

Comment: In particular see the other Stack Overflow answer linked in the GitHub issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176199/scala-parallel-collection-in-object-initializer-causes-a-program-to-hang/15176433#15176433](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176199/scala-parallel-collection-in-object-initializer-causes-a-program-to-hang/15176433#15176433)