# Scala list.par stdout dissapears

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, databricks

I'm trying to map elements of a list and print some logs about the progress. But when I parallelise list, my stdout logs just stop appearing.

Why are they gone? Shouldn't the `stdout` of all threads go to the same place?

```scala
> List(1,2,3,4).map(println(_))
1
2
3
4
res1: List[Unit] = List((), (), (), ())
```

```scala
> List(1,2,3,4).par.map(println(_))
res2: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Unit] = ParVector((), (), (), ())
```

Looks weird. Am I missing something here?
I'm doing it in Databricks, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Done `List(1,2,3,4).par.foreach(print)` works ?

Comment: nope. `List(1,2,3,4).par.foreach(print)` does not print any results for me. However, `List(1,2,3,4).foreach(print)` works as expected and gives "1234".

Comment: Both cases are just hanging in my REPL (Scala 2.12.8, JDK 1.8.0_222)

Comment: Where and how are you running this?

Comment: I'm running it in a Databricks notebook.

Comment: @ViacheslavShalamov probably such environment is not suited for parallel processing, at least not for printing, probably each thread lost connection with the notebook shell, so even if they printed out to the std that wasn't passed to the notebook.

Comment: it's a REPL issue:

[details about the bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8119),
[explanation of the root cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176199/scala-parallel-collection-in-object-initializer-causes-a-program-to-hang/15176433#15176433), [lazy val initialization SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html)